# Select2 Plugin don't fill the field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm trying to use [Select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) plugin, but I have a doubt

**JavaScript**

```
$(".js-example-data-array").select2({
        ajax: {
            method: "POST",
            url: "Actions/ColaboradorSvc.ashx",
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {                
                return {
                    idPeriodoGestao: idPeriodoGestao,
                    query: params.term, 
                    start: 0, 
                    limit: 10
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data, page) {
                debugger;
                // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
                // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
                // alter the remote JSON data
                return {
                    results: data
                };
            },
            cache: true
        },
        escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
        minimumInputLength: 1        
    });
```

**UPDATE**

I change the `processResults` event and now it works for auto complete

```
        processResults: function (data, page) {
            var array = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                var modelo = {
                    id: 0,
                    text: '' + data[i].Nome + ''
                };

                array.push(modelo);
            }

            // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
            // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
            // alter the remote JSON data
            return {
                results: array
            };
        },
```

**JSON Returned from my Service**

```
[{
        "Id": 81,
        "IdArea": 270,      
        "Nome": "Adelice Colaço",       
        "FotoPath": null,
        "WorkflowAcoes": true,
        "Ativo": true       
    },
    {
        "Id": 346,
        "IdArea": 211,      
        "Nome": "Adelma Lira da Silva Borges",      
        "FotoPath": null,
        "WorkflowAcoes": true,
        "Ativo": true
    },
    {
        "Id": 276,
        "IdArea": 247,      
        "Nome": "Adilene Fernandes Da Silva",       
        "FotoPath": null,
        "WorkflowAcoes": true,
        "Ativo": true
    },
    {
        "Id": 277,
        "IdArea": 247,      
        "Nome": "Adriana Dias Silva Porto",     
        "FotoPath": null,
        "WorkflowAcoes": true,
        "Ativo": true
    },
    {
        "Id": 82,
        "IdArea": 250,      
        "Nome": "Agnes Jakobovitsch Costa",     
        "FotoPath": null,
        "WorkflowAcoes": true,
        "Ativo": true
    }]
```

**Rendered**

Bellow, I was expecting an auto complete with the firt register in JSON in "Nome" property, `Adelice Colaço` but doesn't works

[image]

Comment: With your latest update, are you still running into an issue?

Comment: @KevinBrown no, but this isn't the right way to do it. I just create a new array of a specific object